# How do we create object of our entity type from Diff result in Javers

Tags: java, javers

I just found Javers and I have went through basic stuff. I have a situation where I would need to create an object with all fields as null except for those that have been changed between the left and right objects. So is there an easy mechanism to use the Diff object returned by Javers.compare(obj1, obj2) ?

For eg. Consider the Person Entity,

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class Person{
@Id
String name;
int age;
String address;
}

...
Person person1 = new Person('Bob', 20, 'Brooklyn');
Person person2 = new Person('Bob', 30, 'Brooklyn')
//initialize etc.
Diff diffs = Javers.compare(person1, person2);
//Using diffs obj how do I construct person3 with values Person['Bob', 30, null] (address is null since it did not change) ?
...
```

On calling compare() how do I create or derive(from left or right object) easily this person3 object? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you would like to express a diff between two Persons also as a Person object? Why not simply use a Diff object?

Comment: @BartekWalacik Yes, I would need a Person object to feed to a PUT (which will persist the fields that have values as an update on the DB) on the Person RESTful service. So a Diff would not be suitable.

Comment: JaversRepository does this job. Use javers.commit(), see https://javers.org/documentation/repository-examples/